# Is "to mean"an active or stative verb?

Tags: stative-verbs

Is it grammatically correct to write :  "I've been meaning to write to you for ages now "?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is perfectly correct to write **I've been meaning to write to you for ages now**.